# Table format in modal bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

Can I create table in modal bootstrap ?
I make a rows in a table that have a button to preview a rows.

This is my js

```
$('.btn-success').click(function(){
          var address = [];
          $(this).closest('tr').find('td').not(':last').each(function() {

          var textval = $(this).text(); // this will be the text of each <td>
          address.push(textval);
          });

          var hasil = address.join('<br />');

          $("#id_preview").html(hasil);
        });
```

The preview of all My code now is in :

[my code](http://jsfiddle.net/Fadly_Dzil_Massere/xammqf0u/2/)

I wanna the "print" button will be viewing the information of a row.
So , I use js to get them.

My trouble is, How to display that row data on table format in modal bootstrap . Now, I can just grab all of them

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code? which you tried?

Comment: My coode is in jfiddle. The link is in my description above

Comment: Thanks for Cerlin Boss. You're rock.
But, In my case, why action column is not removed ?

Answer (score 0):

I just whipped this up, not sure if it's what you're looking for. I placed a table(with data) inside the modal window and it worked fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/24c6rv7p/

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch demo modal</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Username</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">1</th>
                            <td>Mark</td>
                            <td>Otto</td>
                            <td>@mdo</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">2</th>
                            <td>Jacob</td>
                            <td>Thornton</td>
                            <td>@fat</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">3</th>
                            <td>Larry</td>
                            <td>the Bird</td>
                            <td>@twitter</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/xammqf0u/5/embedded/result/)?

**JQUERY**

```
$('.btn-success').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var $trData = $this.closest('tr').clone();
    $trData.find('td:last').remove();
    var $thData = $this.closest('table').find('thead').clone();
    $thData.find('th:last').remove();
    var $table = $('<table></table>');
    $table.append($thData).append($trData);
    $("#id_preview").html($table);
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

note: for some reasons `modal-backdrop` is having some `z-index` issues in the demo fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for Cerlin Boss. You're rock. But, In my case, why action column is not removed ?

Comment: sry i have updated the fiddle but forgot to update the code snippet. will update.. just a second..